# Assets:precompile rake failing with a ""\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 " error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am having problems precompiling assets for production, the error makes it sound like an encoding problem of some sorts, but I dont know how to find out which file is causing the error.

This is the output of the rake:

http://pastebin.com/254tq8j6

Answer (score 2):

I solved this: it was an asset filename with a non standard character. But I found out the hard way, browsing through all the assets until I found the culprit.

But apparently this particular error indicates a problem with a filename, so I hope this is useful to somebody in the future.